# Using Kubernetes Ingress with HTTPS service

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I'm learning Kubernetes, and want to deploy a Kubernetes Dashboard on my cluster. By default, the dashboard lives on port `30941` and requires a HTTPS connection. This is then and is accessible via my cluster IP. I'd like to setup a domain for this, and I'm using the underneath configuration for this, making use of `--enable-ssl-passthrough`.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
  name: dashboard-ingress
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - dashboard.mydomain.nl
    secretName: kubernetes-dashboard-certs
  rules:
  - host: dashboard.mydomain.nl
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: kubernetes-dashboard
            port:
              number: 30941
```

This works, but is really slow as stated by [the documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/).

> This feature is implemented by intercepting all traffic on the configured HTTPS port (default: 443) and handing it over to a local TCP proxy. This bypasses NGINX completely and introduces a non-negligible performance penalty.

I know you can use a HTTP service in this case, but what if you don't have a choice? I can't imagine Kubernetes not having a native solution for this. How do you normally do this or is there a workaround to make it as fast as the normal way?

Comment: The native solution is to have the Ingress service (nginx) terminate SSL, rather than using this passthrough model you've tried.

Comment: What if you have no other choice? Say a service or pod requires the SSL certificate.

Comment: I think there are other ingress services (e.g., haproxy) that may be able to provide the pass-through SSL service without the same performance hit.  Benchmark a few different ones and see what works best.